# selecting the largest n values and smallest n values simulataneously from a table mySQL

Tags: mysql, limit

In mySQL, I have a database of country names and population I want to return the 5 most populated and 5 least populated countries.  I understanding how to order the results by population and how to limit the results to the top 'n' values or bottom 'n' values of a column, but cannot determine how to return both the top and bottom at the by using one query.

HERE are the two codes separately...

```
SELECT Name, population FROM country 
ORDER BY GNP DESC LIMIT 5; 

SELECT Name, GNP FROM country 
ORDER GNP LIMIT 5;
```

How can I combine these codes into one output??

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL`:

```
(
  SELECT Name, population FROM country 
  ORDER BY population DESC LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT Name, population FROM country 
  ORDER BY population ASC LIMIT 5
)
ORDER by population DESC;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wYE8Ts6NkrCcvhcRJaRFo/0).